# What's the best way to create a "bot account" in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'd like to create a firebase app which allows real users to send messages to each other or to bots.

I'd like real users to be able to register using an oauth provider, which firebase makes easy [like this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account). And once registered they should be able to create a "bot account", which they can be used to authenticate any scripts they want to write, to interact with my firebase app.

An example script could listen for anyone posting a "Hello" message and replies with "Hello to you too!":

```
messagesRef.limitToLast(1).on("child_added", function(childSnapshot) {
  if(childSnapshot.val().body == "Hello"){
    messagesRef.push({
      body: "Hello to you too!"
    });    
  };
});
```

My question is how best to authenticate these bots? I have two ideas

1. Use a service account ([see here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start)). In their script they would call something like this to authenticate:

   ```
   Firebase.initializeApp({
     databaseURL: "https://db.firebaseio.com/",
     serviceAccount: "service-account.json",
     databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
       uid: "user-id"
     }
   });
   ```
2. Allow real users to create bot users by generating a custom token (or I could need to write an online to help them generate and sign this token) and then, in their script they would call:

   ```
   firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)
   ```

The first approach seems to be recommended for servers to connect to firebase, but in my case i'm concerned that these service accounts are too powerful for a user created bots. Grated, it's possible to limit the use of the service account to be that of a normal user (with the databaseAuthVariableOverride), but that is not mandatory so could be abused.

The second approach seems to be designed for integrating custom authentication systems / to achieve SSO but apart from that it looks like it would do the trick. It has the advantage that these bot accounts could be treated just like real users accounts in terms of security rules, etc.

So, which is the best approach or can anyone recommend a better way?

Thanks!
Adam

---

Edit 5/7/16 21:50 GMT

I've been trying to implement option 2 but I think it will fail. Firebase session expire (24hrs default) and so do custom tokens (3600s). So, if my bot is signed out after 24hrs and the custom token can't be used to sign it back in then users will need to generate a new custom token. This won't work - bots should just stay signed in.

This brings me to a third option:

3. Give each bot an email address and password, script authentication in using [signInWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword) and then use [onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) to re-authenticate if the session expires.

This doesn't seem ideal, because it's effectively using email address and password (which were designed for real life users) to authenticate servers, however I'm stuck as to whether option 1 is any better and whether it's even possible to make option 2 work.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

---

Edit 11/7/16 20:36 GMT

Option 3 is not supported directly with the firebase node.js library.

Comment: The best approach is the one that works for all your use-cases. It sounds like using a service account doesn't satisfy your security requirements, so that leaves minting custom tokens for your bots.

Comment: Thanks Frank - and you don't think that's a mis-use of the custom tokens approach? i.e. Are custom tokens mean't for something else?

Comment: And also I'm slightly concerned by this "If you just need to connect to the Firebase Realtime Database from your own server, don't use custom tokens. Instead, use a Firebase server SDK" on this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/#custom_token_creation

Comment: Just trying to implement option 2 now... is it possible to achieve infinite session lengths with signInWithCustomToken()?